# Determine file size of imagepng when used in upload stream

Tags: php

I'm creating a png and uploading immediately to S3, I'd like to log how big that file was without having to do a seperate call to the same file on S3 to work out the size on disk.

Is this possible?

```
$tile = imagecreatetruecolor($tileImageSize, $tileImageSize);

imagecopy($tile, $resizedMainImage, 0, 0, $currentCoordsX, $currentCoordsY, $tileSize, $tileSize);

$writeStream = fopen("s3://bucket/file.png", 'w');

imagepng($tile, $writeStream, 9); // need filesize of this action
```

I've tried wrapping the `imagepng` in `ob_start(); ob_get_length(); etc` with no joy.

Comment: have you tried echo $_FILES[‘pic’][‘size’];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you will need to save the image somewhere in order to get the size. To avoid writing to the filesystem, you can use the memory storage of php. I mean something like this:

```
imagepng($tile, 'php://memory/image.png');
$file_size = filesize('php://memory/image.png');
```

You can do this before uploading the image to the server to have the information for your log.